# python construct to know the list of all the directories and recursive sub-directories

Tags: python

Is there built-in python construct to know the list of all the directories and recursive sub-directories given a directory?Basically i want to run a script lets say "dir.py" on a directory it should list all the directories and the recursive sub-directories...

C:\cwd> dir.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
os.walk('C:\\')
```

There you go.
But we need to go deeper.. well ok then.

```
import os
for root, folders, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    print 'In ' + root + ' There are ' + str(len(folders)) + ' folders and ' + str(len(files)) + '!'
```

But i don't know where i am.. i'm confused.. I.. i.. i can't live without times?! Time is what controls the universe and my mind..

Ok very well then.. as you wish..

```
import os, time
from os.path import abspath
for root, folders, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for f in files:
        (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(abspath(root + '/' + f)
        print f + " was last modified: %s" % time.ctime(mtime)
```

Did we just understand how large the file is too? yes i think we did..
Oh the wonders of programming ;)

Comment: getting a compilation error ..print f + " was last modified: %s" % time.ctime(mtime)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're probably running Python3.X, i don't so you'll probably need to add () to print, such as `print('hey')` :) also try not using %s since i'm not entirely sure that will remain in the future?